# How do i set my Downloads dir in home as default for downloading file?

Tags: permissions, home-directory, downloads, default, ownership

I accidentally moved my **Downloads** folder to some dir in **usr**. I moved it back to **home** but now all my files get downloaded in **Documents** and **Downloads** dir have **root** as **owner** have permission to **create and delete** while **others** have to **acces file**.
How do I change permissions of Downloads and set it as default.

Comment: That will depend on the application you use to download. You moved the folder as administrator, so also act as administrator to restore the appropriate permissions and ownership.

Comment: I am downloading files and stuff via web browser chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the Downloads directory permissions to the default:

```
 sudo chown pukt.pukt /home/pukt/Downloads
 sudo chmod 755 /home/pukt/Downloads
```

where `pukt` is the directory name of your user's home directory.

To set the Downloads directory as your browser's default download directory, you need to go into your browser's Settings dialog.

Comment: This instead changed permissions of all files except two inside the dir to read only

Comment: However i used pukt instead of pukt.pukt and that worked.

Comment: @pulkit Hmm. I thought the directory was empty. My mistake. Sorry. So you're all good now?

Comment: yeah, thank you very much